# Is there any way to easy migrate a CSS to a joomla style classes CSS?

Tags: css, templates, joomla, migration

I'm trying to integrate a CSS file that my designer gave me into a new template in Joomla 1.5. But the HTML content generate by joomla is different than the original CSS that the designer thought. Yes, it uses divs and classes and ids but I'm not sure what the best approach to migrate and implement this is.

Is there any way to tell Joomla to generate tables, divs or `<p>` spans, instead of the default layout? Or to specify some additional classes?

I've seen that the templates that come with the default installation of Joomla have slightly different layouts, but the same classes, one using tables one using divs.

When I create my new template it generates by default tables in the

```
 <jdoc:include type="component" />
```

My main concern is this part. The rest I can even let be NON dynamic, but hardcoded, I tried to make the menu dynamic. When including a module I've seen you can specify a style, but it doesn't really include it:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" style="MyClassName" headerLevel="3" />
```

And I don't know what the `headerLevel` var is for.

A hint anyone?

Answer (score 0):

All of the components and module can be overridden within the templates folder. If you look in the beez folder you will see all of the override files which are hardcoded. You can alter these to have whatever HTML you need. The only problem you might find is when the data coming back to the template is not in the correct format, in which case you would need to hack the model itself.

However, you should be able to change the html in the overrides to achieve most of what you need.

The style="MyClassName" refers to the 'wrapping' that the module receives. Your options in the beez template are set in templates/yourtemplate/html/modules.php. You be able to work out how this works from looking at the code.